# Google play market " Optimization Tips " Tabs

Tags: android

I published my app in Play Market,after verification, in the tab "Optimization Tips" I see, Optimize your app for tablets:APK-file should contain the retractable elements for all common formats Tablet PC screen resolution and gives me the [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#use-tablet-icons).

I slung the section: " Use Assets Designed for Tablet Screens "
Ok
after several attempts to fix this I did not succeed.
I have corrected:

1-my application icon made by all the screens (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi
xxhdpi) I used  New-ImageAsset-Launcher icons;

2-all my Drawable resource matched to the different screens (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi
xxhdpi)

3-all my Layout resource matched to the different screens (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi
xxhdpi)

4-I do not use notification,no action bar icons and notification icons

I do not understand what the problem is why he throws me on " Use Assets Designed for Tablet Screens ". I can not solve it already 2 day, if someone faced such problem please describe how you solved it. Thanks for the answer.